# Delphi 2010, DeHL, file not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, search-path, dehl

Have installed trial version of Delphi 2010, and hoped to get a look at [DeHL](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?page_id=162).

There must be something that I have missed out on, though, cause I can't find out how to include any of the units without getting a 'file not found'-error at compile time...

What I have done, is to include the path to the pas-files in the projects 'Include file search path'. I also  tried to build with packages, but it couldn't find the DeHL-package.
I also tried to include the bin-path where all of DeHLs dcu-files are, but no result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have not included source file paths to the library path list. 
To do so:

- Go to Tools>Options>Environment Options>Delphi Options>Library-Win32
- Add DeHL's src (and all sub folders) to the library path list

also

- Included paths to Compiler Options>Search Paths of the project works as well.

Comment: As told in the question, I have included the paths in the projects search path. Shouldn't that be enough? I will try to include it in the global library path too, just in case, but generally, I want all search paths to remain in the project for easier porting to other development boxes.

Comment: I think 'Include File Search Path option' applies to resource compiler. You should have included it to 'Compiler options> Search Paths' of the project. That works too.

Comment: Wow. I guess you're right. I included the paths in the resource compilers search path. Now, where is the 'accept comment as answer'-button?